# What should be the path to use Ungit with Nitrous IO?

Tags: nitrousio

I'm trying to use Ungit with a github repo I have on a Nitrous box. I'm trying to figure out what the path should be.

For example - my github repo is in located at ~/learn-rails - so in the Ungit 'path' box I put: http://learn-rails-14513.usw1.actionbox.io:\~/learn-rails/ - and got a 'not valid path' error.

Ungit claims to work with cloud computing environments, and see no reason why it wouldn't, but I figure I must be missing something.

You can find the ungit info at https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the command `ungit` in your `~/learnrails/` directory, you will be able to navigate to **Preview > Port 8080** to view ungit (as long as ungit is still running in the console). This means that the URL will not include any subfolders within the URL. The preview URL should look closer to this:

> http://learn-rails-14513.usw1.actionbox.io:8080

Ensure that you have performed the configuration step within the [README](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit) to use port 8080, and this will work out.

*Note: You may be interested in using [tmux](http://help.nitrous.io/faq-disconnect/) as well if you want to keep ungit running after you close the console.*

Comment: This definitely helps a lot! Thank you. However, I'm able to see Ungit (the big logo) - but its not showing the actual repository. I'm just seeing the big Ungit logo, and nothing else, with nothing under 'recent repositories'. Is there something I should be typing into the bar at the top of the screen?